# Is there a way to make this div visible?

Tags: css, reactjs

Now I have some navbar on a page. I've added everything but one of the links disappears. I just can't see it. On inspecting, you can see it on the console but it is not there in the foreground.

here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import { GiHambugerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";
import { MdOutlineRestaurantMenu } from "react-icons/md";
import images from "../../constants/images";

import "./Navbar.css";

const Navbar = () => (
  <nav className="app__navbar">
   <div className="app__navbar-logo">
     <img src={images.gericht} alt="App  Logo" />
   </div>
  <ul className="app__navbar-links">
    <li className="p__opensans">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#Awards">Awards</a>
  </li>
  <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div className="app__navbar-login">
  <a href="#login" className="p__opensans">
    Log in / Register
  </a>
  <div />
  <a href="/" className="p_opensans">
    Book Table
  </a>
</div>
</nav>
);

export default Navbar;
```

and the CSS

```
.app__navbar-login a:hover {
   border-bottom: 1px solid var (--color-golden);
  }
.app__navbar-login div {
   width: 1px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: var(--color-grey);
}
```

The bar shows all the links except the last one tagged Book Table

Please help[This is the screenshot of the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHBpr.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra closing div

```
import React from "react";
import { GiHambugerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";
import { MdOutlineRestaurantMenu } from "react-icons/md";
import images from "../../constants/images";

import "./Navbar.css";

const Navbar = () => (
  <nav className="app__navbar">
   <div className="app__navbar-logo">
     <img src={images.gericht} alt="App  Logo" />
   </div>
  <ul className="app__navbar-links">
    <li className="p__opensans">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#Awards">Awards</a>
  </li>
  <li className="p__opensans">
    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div className="app__navbar-login">
  <a href="#login" className="p__opensans">
    Log in / Register
  </a>
  <div /> <------------------------------------------------- HERE
  <a href="/" className="p_opensans">
    Book Table
  </a>
</div>
</nav>
);

export default Navbar;
```